# Trouble running Python Celery as a daemon

Tags: linux, python, daemon

I have Celery setup and running as a daemon on a Ubuntu EC2 instance. This morning I updated some of the tasks and tried to restart Celery and it wasn't working. After working at it a bit I found:

- Celery *will* start if I run the command `sudo /usr/local/bin/celeryd --time-limit=300 -f /var/log/celeryd.log -l INFO` (which is the command that the init script is using).
- Celery *will not* run if I run `sudo service celeryd start`. In this case the startup script will report that it was started and a `.pid` file will be created in `/var/run`, but the process does not exist/is stopped.

Are there any hints on how to fix this issue? I reverted all of the changes to both my tasks file and the celeryconfig module, but that did not seem to help it running as a daemon. I'm using the [init scripts from the git repo](https://github.com/ask/celery/tree/master/contrib/debian/init.d).

Answer (score 3):

The issue in my case was due to file permissions. The `celeryconfig` and `tasks` files were not readable by the user I was using for Celery. I figured this out by removing the `--background` option from the the `init.d` script and then seeing a Python import error.